# How to set a file name with a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code which enables me to save any text I want to a file with a preset name - `TextToFile`:

```
def Write():
    global Hammer
    print("What do you want to write in the document?\n")
    Hammer = input()
    TextToFile = [Hammer]
    f = open('TextToFile.txt', 'w')
    f.writelines(TextToFile)
    f.close()
    Open()
```

I want to let the user also enter the file name they want for it. How would I go about this?

Comment: You already know how to use `input()`, evidently. Have you considered using that function to specify a filename yet?

Comment: why is `Hammer` upper cased and marked as global?

Comment: Hammer is in upper case as I naturally am like that with names etc. Plus it's marked as a global as it is called up many other times in the script I pulled the code from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name parm to open can be a variable so:

```
    fname = input('File to open ')
    f = open(fname, 'w')
```